# ReactJS Functional Component Renders Multiple Times and Setting Img Src With Props

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, use-effect

I am a newbie in ReactJS and I am trying to pass an object as a props to a component. I am getting data from the .NET CORE WEB API and there is no problem about it. Here is my useEffect hook to do that:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
      
        const response = axios.get("http://localhost:5122/GetUserInfo", { params: { userId: profileId } });
        response.then((res) => {
            setUserInfo(res.data);
        })
    }, [])
```

And I pass the userInfo state as props, as shown below:

```js
    return (
        <div>
        <ProfileCard user={userInfo} />
        </div>
    );
```

To better understand of problem I took a screenshot of console. I am print user prop at the top of `ProfileCard` component.
[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BL3l.png)

My problem is:
When I try to use props such as `<label>{user.profilePicture}</label>` I can see the file name on the screen but when I try to use props such as `<img src={require(./File/${user.profilePicture})} />` cannot see the image on the screen and throws an error to console that basically saying cannot find the image. `Note:`I am sure that given source path is correct and image file exist.

Anybody help me please? Edit: I also added the console error.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows that `profilePicture` is a filename à la `36ddd13a-d3b9-47ad-9719-7789892a1384.jpg`.

- Just doing `<img src={profilePicture} />` would have your browser attempt to find the file by relative path, which is likely not to work.
- `require(...)` only works for assets that are available at the build time of your React app and only for static strings due to bundling; an arbitrary filename that comes over the wire from your API won't be that.
- If your HTTP server serves those images from under `/File`, then you'd need to do

  ```
  <img src={`/File/${profilePicture}`} />
  ```

  (or, if that HTTP server is not the same origin your React app is served from, but that `http://localhost:5122/` from above),

  ```
  <img src={`http://localhost:5122/File/${profilePicture}`} />
  ```

  ).

  - If you're using e.g. create-react-app, then you'd need to put the file in the `/public/File/` directory.

Comment: Thank you for attention and answer. But I don't think problem is about giving the src path. While react app open at the page that using the image, if I try one of the following codes (`<img src={require('./File/' + user.profilePicture)} />` or `<img  src={require(./File/${user.profilePicture})} />` ) I see the image displays on the screen. But when I come from another page I still get the same error that says cannot find the image. Any idea why? I also added console error screenshot to my question that I mentioned if you want to check.

Comment: You can't correctly use `require` here, trust me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass dynamic strings to `require` like `require(./File/${user.profilePicture})`

It maybe work sometimes, but only in some edge cases.

What you should do is tell the compiler exactly which files it needs to bundle:

```js
const map = {
  'profilePic_1': require('./File/profilePic_1'),
  'profilePic_2': require('./File/profilePic_2'),
  // and so on...
}
```

By creating a map you can then "index" the bundled files based on server response.

```
<img src={map[user.profilePicture]} />
```

If you have a fairly large number of images I'd recommend dynamically loading them:

```
const map = {
  'profilePic_1': () => import('./File/profilePic_1'),
  'profilePic_2': () => import('./File/profilePic_2'),
  // and so on...
}

const YourComponent = ({userProfilePicture})
{
  // without placeholder
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('');

  // if you want to load a placeholder from a server
  // const [url, setUrl] = useState('http://placeholder_url');

  // if you want to bundle the placeholder
  // const [url, setUrl] = useState(require('./placeholder_url'));

  useEffect(() => {
    map[userProfilePicture]().then(setUrl);
  }, []);

  return <img src={url} alt=''/>;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please can you post the entire component with the useEffect and also the ProfileCard component.

It might be a problem with the useState.
You should have something like

```
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<TypeOfGetUserInfo | null>(null)
```

In you ProfileCard you should have something like

```
const ProfileCard = React.FC<ProfileCardProps> = ({user}) => {


...

  return (
   ...something
  )
}
```

Comment: this question does not tag TS nor you should be asking for more details in an answer